# Make a content "dynamic" in Typo3

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I am using Typo3 6.2.31

I have created an html content on a page. The html code is a Modal Popup with my own styling, which consists of a title, subtitle, main content and background image.

The goal I want to achieve is :

- Create a form on the backend which I can use to fill (title, subtitle, content, background img)
- use the filled form's value to define my html content (title etc). so anytime someone wants to change the content on the popup modal, it can be done trough the backend form.

Creating an extension seems much effort,
using the existing popup modal extensions has limited flexibility to adjust based on the modal popup design I made. (or is there anyone can refer to a adjustable modal extension?)

So, how can I achieve that goal?
I would love to hear any possible solutions from typo3 users/expert out there :)

Comment: You can use DCE extension available in the TER. This will help you to create an Dynamic element. Here is the [link](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/dce). you can get the reference for quick start from the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/dce/).

Comment: please verify your used version of TYPO3. there is no Version 6.3 released. current versions are: 7.6.21 and 8.7.4

Comment: @GhanshyamBhava apparent DCE is only compatible on 7 & 8 LTS . Tried to install it but the compatibility issue occurred. maybe I'll try older version

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ it is 6.2.31

Comment: I have tried DCE, but apparently I had a problem fluid templating, since my html consist of bunch of java script and separate css, I could not find a way to converting my HTML to Fluid based template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to build your own contentelements (=CEs).
and with the help of some extensions it is not complicated, you do not need to be a programmer.

One of the easiest and cleanest[1] solutions is the combination of the two extensions "ext:**mask**" and "ext:**mask_export**".
While you can create new CEs with ext:mask (which can be used at once), you can export your CE-definition as an own extension with ext:mask_export, so your new CEs can be used without ext:mask installed.
You can define the rendering of FE or BE preview with fluid.

[1] many tools for defining new CEs use the possibilities to store data as XML in the special field pi_flexform. This is easy to handle as TYPO3 supports it, but this data handling has it's drawbacks: without your own fields the access is slow and complicated. e.g. queries for records containing special values in a field.
With ext:mask you can (re)use the existing fields of the tt_content record (representing a CE) or add real database fields to that record.

Comment: The Mask extension, is somehow easy to start with, but I don't know how to build the front end element based on my HTML I have created, now, I am a bit stuck and considering to work on an extension builder.. any suggestion?

Comment: With the ExtensionBuilder (EB) you need to do all the things mask is doing for you by hand. Read the [manual of mask](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/mask/). You need to configure a folder for your templates and create fluid templates as usual.

Comment: I follow all the guide and successfully to display the value from my mask element. But, the template I create on (content/Layouts/myhtml.html) apparently ignores the css, js, html tag, it only prints the value

Comment: How should I include a css and js in a single file on a fluid based template?

Comment: that is another topic

Comment: Nope, I did it. Thank you @bernd the mask did the trick very well, the output is perfect. I successfully created exactly like what I want. The styling, js works fine.. now. exporting it as an extension :)